# Can You Use PHP in A Tumblr Theme?

Tags: php, css, styles, tumblr

I want to use a PHP variable within a tumblr theme so that photo sizes are random. Is it possible to use PHP within a tumblr custom theme or is it its own language/API that doesn't allow PHP inline?

Comment: No. Why you don't use javascript to resize images?

Comment: How so within tumblr? Basically what I have is a <div class="post"> and I want to add <div class="post" style="width:xxx">, xxx being a variable I can plug in because tumblr only lets you edit the css classes for all posts instead of resizing them individually

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript

Comment: No, But I have three solutions for you (**PHP** via Tumblr Api, **CSS** via Tumblr theming and **javascript** way )

Answer (score 2):

No because it will cause security vulnerabilities and that is the reason why they are using [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) in their themes. <s>I'm also quite sure that tumblr isn't written in PHP.</s>

Comment: This is an interesting article about tumblr architecture... http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/2/13/tumblr-architecture-15-billion-page-views-a-month-and-harder.html

Comment: Software that Tumblr uses: PHP, Scala, Ruby (Napolux's link), so apparently they do use PHP

Comment: I don't think they use mustache..

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research and I think this method using tags is maybe the best, at least the most user friendly:

[Can you customize the format of a Tumblr post based on its tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106397/can-you-customize-the-format-of-a-tumblr-post-based-on-its-tag?rq=1)

I set a few different classes in the CSS for my clients, .small, .medium, .large. Now they can just tag with any of those three words and the photo will be resized accordingly. The only drawback is that the tags are visible within tumblr's photo stream so you might see "#small" or something like that. I'd rather not have this but I can't really think of an easier way for the user to easily add a class to a post.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use PHP variables in Tumblr themes, because Tumblr using their own templating engine instead of PHP.

Only one *real* variables variable you can create with Tumblr themes are **[Theme appearance options](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#appearance-options)**, but they are common for all theme.

#### You have several possible solution:

- Use [**Tumblr API**](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) on your own project with PHP.
- Use **“[Create a custom HTML theme](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)”**  guide for creating customizations classes (with css) per post, like I'm doing in my developed [Hampi theme](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/blob/master/compiled.html):

  ```
  <article id="post{PostID}" class="
      {PostType}
      {block:PostNotes}hasnotes{block:PostNotes}
      {block:More}hasmore{/block:More}
      {block:HasTags}hastags{/block:HasTags}
      {block:Date}
          postdate-{AmPm}
          postdate-{ShortDayOfWeek}
          postdate-{ShortMonth}
          postdate-{DayOfMonthWithZero}
          postdate-{Year}
      {/block:Date}
      {TagsAsClasses}
  ">
  ```
- Use **javascript** (*jQuery*, actually) for modifying styles for *each* post with random values of width, like in this **[demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/Kue6A/4/)**:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $.each($('.post'), function(i, post) {
          var max = 800,
              min = 500,
              rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min);

          $(post).css('width', rand);
      });
  });​
  ```

  With this result for `max=200` and `min=100`:
  [image]