# Tumblr Theme PHP Count

Tags: php, jquery, count, themes, tumblr

Can I use a php counter in a tumblr theme?

I would like to use the counter to add a class to every 4th post, example:

```
<div class="<?php if($i % 4 == 0) {echo 'noCol';} ?>">
    {post}
</div>
```

is this possible or is there a jQuery option? I know I could achieve the same thing using css but this is not cross browser friendly!

Comment: Yes, the example you posted is legit.

Answer (score 1):

Using Theme Operators:

```
class="{block:Post4}noCol{/block:Post4}{block:Post8}noCol{/block:Post8}{block:Post12}noCol{/block:Post12}"
```

Using CSS:

```
.post:nth-child(4n) {  /* styles for noCol here */ }
```

*the only browser that doesn't support `nth-child` is IE8 http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child*

This is solvable with out jQuery or javascript.

Comment: The CSS solution has a potential problem. It relies on particular HTML structure, which might not be in place. Say, after every post there's a separator <div>. Suddenly you've selected twice as many posts.

Comment: @Denis correct. However I believe that is a design issue, which can be solved by revising the markup, rather than waiting for a javascript library to load to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, you [can't run PHP in Tumblr themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109428/can-you-use-php-in-a-tumblr-theme).
But you can easily do it with JavaScript:

```
$('.post').filter(function(i){ return i % 4 === 0; }).addClass('noCol');
```

Comment: Beat me to it...alternatively, you could do `$('.post:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('noCol');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I thought about that. But it relies on particular HTML structure, which might not be the case. Say, after every post there's a separator <div>. Suddenly you've selected twice as many posts.

Comment: excellent point, I shall leave the comment in case it assists someone in the future. +1 nontheless.